# How many elements may python dictionary hold?

Tags: python, dictionary, out-of-memory

I've just got following output in python console using Windows 7 64-bit and Python 2.7 32-bit:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> for k in xrange(1000000): a[k] = k
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> len(a)
21846
>>> a[21846]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 21846
>>> a[21846] = 21846
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Why I can't add more than 21846 items to dict?

What is specific about this number (2 * 3 * 11 * 331)?

Note: I have a lot more RAM than sys.getsizeof(a) == 393356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Leifingson and @Tim mentioned, this behaviour depends on stuff done before. To illustrate memory consumption I'll use following example:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = {}
>>> for k in xrange(1000000): a['a' * k] = k
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> len(a)
64036
```

If we'll take summary keys length:

```
>>> log(sum(xrange(64036)), 2)
30.93316861532543
```

we'll get near integer overflow!

The tricky part is:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
1573004
```

`sys.getsizeof` returns size of something different, then all items of dict. Maybe it is size of all key hashes, I don't know.

After that done,

```
>>> a = {}
```

will free all 2 Gb of allocated memory, but will leave GC (I blame it) in some crippled state. So executing:

```
>>> for k in xrange(1000000): a[k] = k
```

Will cause:

```
MemoryError
```

And similar to asked "magic" number:

```
>>> len(a)
87382
```

Answer (score 8):

Very surprising!  There's nothing special to Python about 21846.  Here's on 32-bit Windows Vista with Python 2.7.5 and a modest 3 GB of RAM:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> for k in xrange(1000000): a[k] = k
...
>>> len(a)
1000000
```

Can also do it with 10 million.  But this was starting with a fresh console window.  Perhaps you did other stuff before what you showed us, and left behind some large data structures?  21846 is tiny by modern standards ;-)

### Later

This was posted to Python's bug tracker, here:  http://bugs.python.org/issue19246

It was closed as "won't fix", because the same kind of behavior was reproduced by a simple little pure C program.  That is, the system C's `malloc()` and `free()` are to blame, and there's nothing sane Python can do about that.  It appears to be specific to Windows, using Microsoft's C libraries.  The problem is heap fragmentation:  after allocating and free'ing many objects of varying sizes, the system `malloc()` then fails when asked for a "largish" memory block, despite that there are plenty of free bytes available.  But they're not in a single contiguous chunk (at least not in one the system `malloc()` recognizes as such).

Stuff happens ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That is your environment's constraint and has nothing to do with Python dictionaries. So the answer to your question is: A python dictionary can hold as much as your environment allows it to.