# How much data can a dictionary store?

Tags: python, dictionary

How much data sets can a dictionary store? Is there a limit? If so, what defines those limits?

I am just beginning to use Python and would like to understand dictionaries more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many elements may python dictionary hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287103/how-many-elements-may-python-dictionary-hold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries can store a virtually unlimited amount of data sets, limited primarily by the amount of memory available on the computer being used.

The maximum number of items that a dictionary can hold is determined by the amount of memory allocated to the Python interpreter, and the size of each item stored in the dictionary.

A dictionary is implemented as a hash table, which typically uses more memory than other data structures such as lists and arrays. The amount of memory used by a dictionary depends on the number of items stored in the dictionary, as well as the size and complexity of those items.

One way to store more data in a dictionary is to use a "lazy evaluation" approach, where the values for certain keys are not computed and stored in the dictionary until they are actually needed. This can be done by using a function as the value for a key, rather than a pre-computed value.

For example, let's say you have a large dataset that you want to store in a dictionary, but you don't want to use up all of your memory by loading the entire dataset into memory at once. Instead, you could create a dictionary with keys corresponding to different subsets of the dataset, and values that are functions that generate the corresponding subsets when called.

```
def load_data_subset(start, end):
    # code to load and return a subset of the dataset
    return subset

data = {
    'subset_1': lambda: load_data_subset(0, 10000),
    'subset_2': lambda: load_data_subset(10000, 20000),
    # etc.
}

# To access a subset of the data, you would call the corresponding function
subset_1 = data['subset_1']()
```

In this way, the data is only loaded into memory when it is actually needed, and the memory usage is limited to the size of the subsets being used at any given time.This approach allows you to store large amounts of data without using up all of your memory at once.

It's important to notice that this approach may have performance drawbacks when compared to pre-loading all the data into memory, but it's a good solution when the data can't fit into memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard limit to the size of a dictionary, except the amount of RAM available on your system. For a more practical answer, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62266754/20103413).